# Second order differential equation regarding discriminant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to wrap my head around this problem but cannot seem to find inspiration on how to get started. So, let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive constants and $b^2-4ac>0$. Let $u(t)$ solve the differential equation

$$au\prime\prime+bu\prime+cu=0, ~~~~~~~~u(0)=u_0, u\prime(0)=v_0$$

How can I show that if $v_0=0$, then $u(t)$ is never $0$ for positive $t$? Also, why can $u(t)$ be $0$ for only one positive $t$? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Find the archetype of your solution. It should contain exponential functions ($e^x$) which are key with this analysis. I will sketch a solution to the second question in the comments.

Comment: Ok, so the positive discriminant suggests two real roots in which case the general solution to the homogeneous equation would look something like $c_1e^{r_1u}+c_2e^{r_2u}$. Is this going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes although I imagine you meant to type \$ u = c_1e^{r_1 t} + c_2e^{r_2 t}\$ to get $ u = c_1e^{r_1 t} + c_2e^{r_2 t}$. Remember that $u$ is your function that you are solving for and that you should put everything in the exponent of anything in {}.

Comment: Ok, it's been edited. Now, do I substitute in the initial conditions?

Comment: Yes. Although make sure you have a $t$ instead of a $u$ in your exponent. $u$ is a function of another variable (usually $t$ or $x$). Recall that you are looking for a function $u(t)$ that solves the equation. Your end result should contain no $u$'s in this case (although implicit solutions may arise in other cases).

Comment: I get that $u(0)=c_1+c_2$ and $u\prime(0)=c_1r_1+c_2r_2$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13509/discussion-between-brad-and-rxy15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $au'' + bu' + cu = 0$. The characteristic equation $ar^2  +br +c$ has two distinct real roots because $b^2 - 4ac \gt 0$. Call these roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Without loss of generality, $\lambda_1 \gt \lambda_2$.

The solution to our equation is now $$ u = c_1e^{\lambda_1t} + c_2e^{\lambda_2t}.$$
for constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. Set $u = 0$.

$$c_1e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2e^{\lambda_2 t} = 0$$

$$ c_2e^{\lambda_2 t} = -c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}$$

$$ -\frac{c_2}{c_1} = \frac{e^{\lambda_1 t}}{e^{\lambda_2 t}}$$

Let $C = \frac{-c_2}{c_1}$ and $\lambda_0 = \lambda_1 - \lambda_2$

$$ C = e^{\lambda_0 t}$$

If your value of $C$ is less than or equal to $0$ there is no solution for any $t$. Your initial conditions may result in $C > 0$ but I have not checked this. Otherwise there is a unique solution for $t$ which is $t =  \dfrac{\log(C)}{\lambda_0} $why is this unique?

Now to consider the first problem.

I will adopt new notation. Notice that $a, b$ and $c$ are all positive so the sum of the roots is equal to $\frac{-b}{a}$ and the product is equal to $\frac{c}{a}$. This means that our two roots are both negative. Let our solution be $$ u  = c_1e^{-r_1 t} + c_2e^{-r_2 t}. $$ In this instance, both $r_1$ and $r_2$ are positive. If $u'(0) = 0$ we can quickly arrive at the equality $-c_1r_1 - c_2r_2 = 0$ and solve for $c_1 = \dfrac{-c_2r_2}{r_1}$. Plugging this in to our original equation and setting it equal to zero we find that $$ u = \frac{-c_2r_2}{r_1}e^{-r_1 t} + c_2e^{-r_2 t} = 0.$$

Divide by $c_2$ and rearrange.

$$\frac{-r_2}{r_1}e^{-r_1 t} + e^{-r_2 t} = 0$$

$$\frac{r_2}{r_1}e^{-r_1 t} = e^{-r_2 t}$$

Multiply by $e^{r_1 t}$

$$\frac{r_2}{r_1} = e^{(r_1-r_2) t}$$

It cannot be that $r_1 = r_2$ because then we would have only one linearly independent solution. If $r_1 > r_2$, $e^{(positive)\cdot t} = \frac{r_2}{r_1}$. This cannot be true (for $t \geq 0$) because $e^{(positive)\cdot t} \geq 1$  and $\frac{r_2}{r_1} \lt 1$.

Similarly, if $r_2 > r_1$, $e^{(negative)\cdot t} = \frac{r_2}{r_1}$. This cannot be true because $e^{(negative)\cdot t} \leq 1$  and $\frac{r_2}{r_1} \gt 1$.

Thus, we have a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But, thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=e^{-λt}v(t)$. Then $u'(t)=e^{-λt}(-λv+v')$ and $u''(t)=e^{-λt}(λ^2v-2λv'+v'')$, so that the differential equation transforms to
$$
0=a(λ^2v-2λv'+v'')+b(-λv+v')+cu=av''+(b-2λa)v'+(λ^2a-λb+c)v
$$
with $v(0)=u(0)=u_0$ and $0=u'(0)=-λv(0)+v'(0)$, i.e., $v'(0)=-λv(0)=λu_0$

Multiply by $4a$ and reduce the linear term to zero, $0=b-2λa$ or $λ=b/(2a)$, reduces the equation to
$$
0=4a^2v''+(4ac-b^2)v
$$
If it were $4ac-b^2>0$, one would get an oscillator equation with a sinusoidal solution that surely will take negative values.

However, for the opposite case, $b^2-4ac>0$, the solution can be expressed in hyperbolic functions. Or more elementary, 
$$
v''(t)=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}v(t)
$$
and from the mean value theorem it follows that there is no smallest $t>0$ with $v'(t)=0$ and also no $t>0$ with $v(t)=0$, since $v(0)$ and $v'(0)$ are positive. Moreover, $v(t)$ is increasing and convex for $t>0$.